# Loop through folder full of text files, grab values for variables, match & populate CSV with storeID and variable name

Tags: python, excel, csv

super new to Python, and looking for some guidance. I'm trying to 
loop through hundreds of text files in a folder (one for each store), and generate a CSV file with the store ID (given in the title of the text document i.e. xxx2902ncjc), and various parameters about the store (i.e. maxPeople=31, or space_temp=78, etc.). Each text file may have difference parameters depending on the location, so I've captured all of the unique variables in the third for loop below. I've captured all of the store IDs in the second for-loop. That's all I've gotten so far.

Challenges that I'm seeing are 1) figuring out how to import this all to Excel, 2) Finding someway to store IDs (which are at this point a slice of each filename) with the correct parameters 3) Finding a way to have excel match up the Store ID and the parameters to the variables.

I honestly have no idea what I should be doing next. Any and all help would be very appreciated as I am a suuuper novice. Cheers.

```
import os, sys, glob
path = r"C:\Users\XXXXX" #insert folder for data here
dirs=os.listdir(path)
fullfilenames=[]
variablelist=[]
allvariables=[]
variables=[]
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if ".prop" in file:
        fullfilenames.append(path+'\\'+file)

for name in fullfilenames: #create list of StoreIDs
    index_of_c = name.index('qPA')
    file_name= name[index_of_c:] #cuts off path
    file_name=file_name.rsplit(".",1)[0] #removes extension
    SiteID= file_name[4:] #splits filename into Site ID
    print (SiteID) #prints SiteID

for file in fullfilenames:
    f = open(file,'r') #opens the file and enters reading mode
    content=f.readlines() #reads each line of file and seperates based on whitespace
    for line in content:
        variables.append(line.split('=')[0]) #splits up each line of each file, specified before the "="
        for variable in variables:
            if variable not in allvariables: #checks if variable is included in the variable list
                allvariables.append(variable) #if variabe isn't include in the list, it adds it to list


def createkeys():

print(allvariables)
print(type(allvariables))
print(len(allvariables))
```

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show at least 3 Lines of Data from a `.prop` File and your expected Output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os, sys, glob, re
path = r"C:\Users\mcantwell\Desktop\Projects\kohls_prop" #insert folder for data here
outfile = r"C:\Users\mcantwell\Desktop\Projects\kohls_prop.csv"
dirs=os.listdir(path)
fullfilenames=[]
variablelist=[]
allvariables=set()
variables=[]
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if ".prop" in file:
        fullfilenames.append(path+'\\'+file)

for file in fullfilenames:
    f = open(file,'r') #opens the file and enters reading mode
    content=f.readlines() #reads each line of file and seperates based on whitespace
    for line in content:
        line_split = line.split('=') #splits up each line of each file, specified before the "="
        if len(line_split) == 2:
            variable = line_split[0]
            allvariables.add(variable)

out = open(outfile, 'w')

def writerow(row):
    out.write(', '.join(row))
    out.write('\n')

writerow(['SiteID'] + list(allvariables))

for file in fullfilenames:
    m = re.search('qPAC(\d+)', file)
    SiteID = m.group(1)
    f = open(file,'r') #opens the file and enters reading mode
    content=f.readlines() #reads each line of file and seperates based on whitespace
    data={}
    for line in content:
        line_split = line.strip().split('=') #splits up each line of each file, specified before the "="
        if len(line_split) == 2:
            variable = line_split[0]
            value = line_split[1]
            data[variable] = value
    values = [SiteID] + [data.get(variable, '') for variable in allvariables]
    writerow(values)

print(allvariables)
print(type(allvariables))
print(len(allvariables))
```